# set tag name for Robot Testcases

Tags: robotframework

I want to run a robot testcase with specific tagname for identify my testcase in group of testcases. I tried to give the tagname in tagname tag box in Ride , but it is not working for some times.Is there any other way to give tagname for testcases..

Comment: What you mean when u say it does not work sometimes?..any example,error?

Comment: It is expected that questions at [so] meet certain criteria. These are described in the [ask] page that I strongly suggest you read as your question does not meet these. In addition we expect a certain level of effort to already have been spent on your part and are not merely asking for a ready-made solution. As the answer to this question is specifically described in the Robot Framework User guide, I am left with the impression that you did not spend much time on investigating the problem and certainly not on writing this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robotframework docs to the rescue: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases

Open testsuite in any text editor and check if testcases have [Tags] entry in their body. Additionally you can set default tags for whole test suite by using `Default Tags` in `Settings`

> Tags are free text, but they are normalized so that they are converted to lowercase and all spaces are removed. If a test case gets the same tag several times, other occurrences than the first one are removed. Tags can be created using variables, assuming that those variables exist.

Example from docs (check the docs for details,how to run testcases by tags name is described in other part of docs http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-tag-names):

```
*** Settings ***
Force Tags      req-42
Default Tags    owner-john    smoke

*** Variables ***
${HOST}         10.0.1.42

*** Test Cases ***
No own tags
    [Documentation]    This test has tags owner-john, smoke and req-42.
    No Operation

With own tags
    [Documentation]    This test has tags not_ready, owner-mrx and req-42.
    [Tags]    owner-mrx    not_ready
    No Operation
```

Comment: yes, you can add multiple tags,duplicates will be handled (Robot will remove duplicates in parsing phase). Remember to separate tag items by separator (<tab> or <space><space> depending on your file type)

Answer (score 0):

Tags provides flexibility for robot test execution.

Try following method.

1. Provide tags at suite level - all testcases under suite inherit tags from suite.
2. Provide the tags for testcases which are not ready to run ( example tags : NotReady/UnderTest etc)
3. Execute robot testcases By tag names provide --include and --exclude option

Snippet from Robot user guide for quick reference

> It is possible to include and exclude test cases by tag names with the
>   --include (-i) and --exclude (-e) options, respectively. If the --include option is used, only test cases having a matching tag are selected, and with the --exclude option test cases having a matching
>   tag are not. If both are used, only tests with a tag matching the
>   former option, and not with a tag matching the latter, are selected.
>
> --include example
>   --exclude not_ready
>   --include regression --exclude long_lasting Both --include and --exclude can be used several times to match multiple tags. In that case a test is selected if it has a tag that matches any included
>   tags, and also has no tag that matches any excluded tags.